# Ошибка при работе с дженериками "Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "int" в "field""

Tags: c#, generics

```
public class Matrix<field> {
    public int Line {
        get; private set;
    }
    public int Column {
        get; private set;
    }
    public field[,] Mas {
        get; private set;
    }
    public field this[int i, int j] {
        get {
            return Mas[i, j];
        }
        private set {
            Mas[i, j] = value;
        }
    }
    public static Matrix<field> Identity_Matrix(int n) {
        Matrix<field> temp = new Matrix<field>(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
              temp[i, i] = 1;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

В строке `temp[i,i] =1;` возникает ошибка:

> CS0029    Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "int" в "field"

Изучаю C#, и пока не разобрался, как можно реализовать иначе, избегая данной ошибки?

Comment: Вместо 1 напишите `default (field) `

Comment: Не с шаблонами, а с генериками. В шарпе это так называется

Comment: Вам стоит приложить код для класса ``field``. Сейчас вы пытаетесь присвоить переменной типа ``field`` переменную типа ``int``, что приводит к ошибке.